# can i blend up concord grapes seed and all for a pie?

Tags: pie, grapes

I am making a Concord Grape pie and was thinking of blending the grapes in a Vita Mix seeds and all then cook the mix according to the recipe, has anyone done this?

Comment: If you have a food mill, it's not very hard to just get the seeds out.

Comment: Many grapes produce bitter seeds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grape_seed_extract

Answer (score 1):

I neither have, nor would, do this, for the same reason that I spit out seeds when eating seeded grapes.

I suppose you can. It might not taste very good, grape seeds being what they are, taste-wise. But perhaps you like that taste.